# download and save .doc or .docx file android then view file

Tags: java, android

I am trying to download and save a .docx file to the local directory. I am able to achieve that but there is no way I am finding to view the same file to read.

I am getting the file from URL and on click, I am downloading and saving. But unable to open. Please help me with some solution to open the file and read in an app or even somehow if I can suggest downloading apps to view properly ll be good instead of nothing.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The device should have an application that knows how to open those files - like microsoft word for instance.

your application needs to open a file chooser. Try this code:

```
public void openDocument(String name) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    File file = new File(name);
    String extension = android.webkit.MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(Uri.fromFile(file).toString());
    String mimetype = android.webkit.MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);

    // if there is no extension or there is no definite mimetype, still try to open the file
    if (extension.equalsIgnoreCase("") || mimetype == null) {
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "text/*");
    } else {
        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), mimetype);            
    }

    // custom message for the intent
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose an Application:"));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Haggai for the answer it gave an option to select a relevant app to open the file.